# PHP script logic with comparison operators and decimal place

Tags: php, comparison, system, rating

I'm developing the web app and made the (maybe foolish) decision to try and make a rating system rather than implement someone else's.

Below is a screenshot of the web app. The decimal values are the values retrieved from the database. I am using the following logic to turn the value into a star-representation.

```
for($x=1;$x<=$this->retreat->total_review_activities_rating;$x++) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
}
if (strpos($this->retreat->total_review_activities_rating,'.')) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>';
   $x++;
}
while ($x<=5) {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
   $x++;
}
```

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, The value 5.000 is hitting the half star option in the loop. How can I adjust the second argument to avoid this from happening?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rating = $this->retreat->total_review_activities_rating;
```

The number of full stars is the whole number part of the rating.

```
$full_stars = (int) $rating;
echo str_repeat('<i class="fas fa-star"></i>', $full_stars);
```

You display a half star if the decimal portion of the rating exceeds some value of your choice.

```
$half_star = $rating - $full_stars > 0.2;        // 0.2 for example
echo $half_star ? '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>' : '';
```

The number of remaining empty stars is the total number of possible symbols (5) minus the number of symbols displayed so far. (The boolean `$half_star` will be converted to int 0 or 1.)

```
$empty_stars = 5 - ($full_stars + $half_star);
echo str_repeat('<i class="far fa-star"></i>', $empty_stars);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `strpos()` function will always output true since it outputs a position, which under Boolean logic is not 0(false).

Aside from this your code seems overly complex for a pretty simple problem which I would have approached in a different way. **Definitely use the decimals as numerical values, and then use that to generate a number of stars.** Parsing for the period seems silly.

```
while($x > 0) { //While there is still enough rating for a star left
    if($x >= 0.75) {
        //Add a full star
        echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
        $x--; //Remove one start rating
    else if($x < 0.25) {
        //Don't display a start
        $x--; //There isn't enough left for a star so we must be done.
    else {
        //Display a half-star
        echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>';
        $x--; //There is only enough for a half start left so we must be done
    }
}
```

This is all in one loop, doesn't depend on a "limit" rating, and uses less processing time than your solution.
It could even be put in a function given a rating and returning star html.

Comment: How would I use this with my variable $this->retreat->total_review_food_rating

Comment: `function stars($x) {
*enter code above*
}`
Then outside of the function:
`stars($this->retreat->total_review_food_rating);`

Comment: Can you explain why this uses less resources?

Comment: Sure, so the total number of stars displayed will be a linear runtime **O(n)**, or given an n number of intended stars it should run n times, which is what my solution does. 
The question has the for loop run n times to the last integer before the decimal. Then the `strpos()` function runs in linear time once with O(m), where m is the number of digits in the in the string that you are parsing. After this, the while loop will only run in the case that the rating is below 1, but also only in the case that you format your rating strings with a '.' first. Overall your code is bloated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the condition with `strpos`, which is always true.

For example compare AVG and integer.

```
if ($this->retreat->total_review_activities_rating != (int)$this->retreat->total_review_activities_rating) {
   // if (4.800 != 4) {true,  show half star}
   // if (5.000 != 5) {false, no half star}
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>';
   $x++;
}
```